# Defining a consistent Lebesgue measure on the Riemann Sphere

Tags: complex-analysis, metric-spaces, riemann-surfaces

I have to compute the Lebesgue measure of certain subsets of $\bar{\Bbb C}$, which is a Riemann Surface.

What I thought is to apply suitable charts to reduce myself to work with subsets of the complex plane, according to the sets I deal with; if such a set does not touch $\infty$ I just use the identity chart, otherwise, if $U\subset\bar{\Bbb C}$ is the open set I have to measure and $a$ is a point NOT belonging to $U$ I use the inversion centered in a $a$, that is $z\mapsto\frac1{z-a}$ and then I take the Lebesgue measure of this set.

This doesn't seem consistent and I suspect there is something I am ignoring to deal with such a problem, like using certain metrics and so on.

Any hint to make this rigorous? Thanks

**EDIT** Say I have the usual unit disk $\Delta:=\{|z|<1\}$; as a subset of $\Bbb C$ its Lebesgue measure is $2\pi$. From this I can consider $\Delta$ as a subset of $\bar{\Bbb C}$ assigning it the same measure.

Maybe my argument fails when I take the Lebesgue measure of sets of $\Bbb C$ got from $\bar{\Bbb C}$ with *different* charts. But it can be consistent if I choose a point not belonging to *any* of the sets I will consider and use always the same chart. Could this work?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by Lebesgue measure on the Riemann sphere but any Radon measure will assign a finite value to $\overline{\mathbb C}$ because $\overline{\mathbb C}$ is compact. From there you can see that just taking charts and taking the usual Lebesgue measure won't work.

Answer (score 1):

Identify $\mathbb{C}\cup\{\infty\}$ with the standard $\mathbb{S}^2$ via stereographic projection.  Then the spherical metric $ds=2\lvert dz\rvert/(1+\lvert z\rvert^2)$ induces a measure $\mu$ which is
$$\frac{d\mu}{d\lambda_{\mathbb{C}}}(z)=\frac4{(1+\lvert z\rvert^2)^2}$$
where $\lambda_\mathbb{C}$ is the standard Lebesgue measure on $\mathbb{C}\cong\mathbb{R}^2$.  This formula remains the same as long as you are doing stereographic projections onto equatorial planes and $z$ is the coordinate on that plane.  In particular, on $w=1/z$ chart, it is also
$$
\frac{d\mu}{d\lambda_{\mathbb{C}}}(w)=\frac4{(1+\lvert w\rvert^2)^2}.
$$

Note the only isometries of the Riemann sphere are rotations of $\mathbb{S}^2$, which is not the full Mobius group.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. So for example the measure of $\Delta$ under this measure is the lebesgue measure of the image of $\Delta$ under the mapping $z\mapsto\frac4{(1+|z|^2)^2}$, which is $\int_{\Delta}\frac4{(1+|z|^2)^2}dz=2\pi\int_0^1\frac4{(1+r^2)^2}dr$ am I right?

Comment: You are missing the factor $r$ from the Jacobian, and to call it $dz$ would be seriously abusing notation ;)

Comment: Maybe $\int_{\Delta}\frac4{(1+|z|^2)^2}\frac{dz\wedge d\bar z}{-2i}$ is better? XD